# Alternatives to select backfaces without xray mode?

Tags: select

How to select through a mesh without using xray mode?
Would like to select through mesh in Material Preview.

Comment: in *Object* mode or *Edit* mode? Selecting objects inside of another object works with Ctrl+MB or do another click without moving the mouse.

Comment: ... and ,in Object Mode, Alt-Left clicking pops up a menu of objects under the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

In Edit Mode, I *think* you have to <kbd>H</kbd> hide faces.

That can seem annoying, because Blender defaults to selecting any elements you <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> reveal again. But, that's an option, which can be unchecked in the operator's <kbd>F9</kbd> panel..

[image]

.. and that setting sticks after first use.

[image]

Comment: interesting workaround, thanks! In Silo Middle Mouse select will select through any mesh. Trying to not change view modes to make a selection.

Comment: @CountQuadula   Blender, on the whole, doesn't like to let you do anything to things you can't see.